# How to connect to a interactive process in docker container

Tags: docker, go, containers

I want to connect to an interactive process (`python` in this example) on a docker container and get the output ( `2` in this example) printed out. This is not asking how to get the output of a shell command (like `pwd` or `ls -a`)

```
cmd1 := "python"
cmd2 := "p = 1"
cmd3 := "print(p+=1)"

rstid := environment.ExecCmd([]string{cmd1, cmd2, cmd3})
environment.ReturnCmdOutput(rstid) -> expected 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the flags `-i` and `t` in this case. `i` keeps STDIN open and `t` allocates a pseudo terminal.

**Example** which will give you an interactive python session inside a docker container.

`sudo docker run -it --rm python:3.8.1-slim-buster`